# How can i Add Where Condition on a Joined Table in TypeORM & NestJS?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on a project using `TypeORM`, and I'm trying to add a WHERE condition on a column in a joined table. I have a Reservation entity with a many-to-one relationship to a Listing entity. Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
  findAllByUserId(userId: number) {
    return this.reservationRepository.find({
      relations: ['listing', 'listing.favourite'],
      where: { user_id: userId }
    });
  }
```

I am facing issues trying to add a WHERE condition on a column in the listing table.
I'd appreciate any guidance on how to correctly add a condition to the joined table in TypeORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below :

```
  findAllByUserIdWithCondition(userId: number, conditionValue: string): Promise<Reservation[]> {
    return this.reservationRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('reservation')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('reservation.listing', 'listing')
      .innerJoinAndSelect('listing.favourite', 'favourite')
      .where('reservation.user_id = :userId', { userId })
      .andWhere('listing.columnName = :conditionValue', { conditionValue })
      .getMany();
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this approach but i was looking for using `find()` method. If it is possible it would be more appreciated!. But still thanku for your valuable time.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
const reservations = await reservationRepository.find({
  relations: ['listing'],
  where: {
    userId: userId,
    // You can add additional conditions here for the 'listing' relation
    listing: { favourite: true } // replace `true` with your where condition
  },
});
```

this is my code used in my project:

```
const getQuestion = await this.sectionRepository.findOne({
       where: {
          id: sectionId,
          isActive: true,
          questions: {
            isActive: true,
          },
        },
        relations: {
          questions: { subQuestions: { options: true }},
        },
      });
```